# Play animation before and after property changes in a control

Tags: c#, animation, winrt-xaml, dependency-properties

I have built a custom control. One of the properties, named `Date`, is backed up by a dependency property, `DateProperty`. What I want is that, when this property changes, an animation is played, the control then responds to this change, then another animation plays. This is what I have done:

```
public DateTime Date
{
    get
    {
        return (DateTime)GetValue(DateProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        SetValue(DateProperty, value);
    }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Date. This enables animation,
// styling, binding, etc...

public static readonly DependencyProperty DateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Date", typeof(DateTime), typeof(MyCtl), new PropertyMetadata(DateTime.Now, OnDatePropertyChanged));

private static void OnDatePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MyCtl elem = d as MyCtl;
    if (elem != null)
    {
        elem.shrinkStoryboard.Begin();

        // Some irrelevant processing

        // Some processing that modifies the control in response to the property changes

        elem.growStoryboard.Begin();
    }
}
```

This doesn't seem to work. When I commented out one of the storyboards, it worked but then only that storyboard is played, which is what I want. I also noticed that the `BeginTime` and `Duration` values are not considered in the animation.

The animations affect only the `RenderTransform`.

I will update the question if there is any information anyone needs to know.

**EDIT**

The two storyboards, as their names imply, decrease and increase the `ScaleX` and `ScaleY` values of a `ScaleTransform`. As such, I cannot combine them in one storyboard. If anyone needs the XAML, I will post them soon.

### XAML

```
<Storyboard x:Name="shrinkStoryBoard"
            Storyboard.TargetName="shrink"
            Duration="0:0:0.5">
    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
                     To="0.001" />
    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"
                     To="0.001" />
</Storyboard>
<Storyboard x:Name="growStoryBoard"
            Storyboard.TargetName="shrink"
            BeginTime="0:0:0.7"
            Duration="0:0:0.5">
    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
                     To="1" />
    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"
                     To="1" />
</Storyboard>
```

### Code-behind

```
private static void OnDatePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MyCtl elem = d as MyCtl;
    if (elem != null)
    {
        elem.shrinkStoryboard.Begin();

        DateTime date = (DateTime)e.NewValue;
        string month = date.ToString("MMMM").Substring(0, 3);
        string day = date.Day.ToString("D2");
        string year = date.Year.ToString("D4");

        SetImages(elem, month, day, year);

        elem.growStoryboard.Begin();
    }
}

private static void SetImages(MyCtl elem, string month, string day, string year)
{
    elem.dayImage1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(elem.BaseUri, "Assets/images/" + day.Substring(0, 1) + ".png"));
    elem.dayImage2.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(elem.BaseUri, "Assets/images/" + day.Substring(1, 1) + ".png"));
    // And so on... Everything here is setting ImageSources...
}
```

Comment: Did you try have your animation code in property's setter after SetValue method call?

Comment: I believe one should not do have any code in the setter when using a dependency property. I remember reading the purpose is to respect binding, animation etc. That is the purpose of the `PropertyMetadata` argument in the dependency registration, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't (or at least shouldn't be) significant time for the property processing between the two storyboards so your second animation is starting while the first one is still playing. Since they're modifying the same properties that interferes and overrides the first.

The easiest solution would be to use a single storyboard to shrink and then grow--you can probably just set it to autoreverse. If you want to use separate storyboards then wait until the shrinkStoryboard's Completed event fires before Beginning growStoryboard.

Comment: I put significant delay in the second storyboard so that it won't start until some time after the first is complete. I've also tried starting the second storyboard in the completed event of the first. If I were to use a single storyboard, how would I be able to change the content of the control before the second animation starts? That means I have to pause the storyboard after the first part, change the content, then resume. I'll see if that does it.

Comment: If you want to make a change in the middle then two storyboards will be better. Based on what you've posted, starting the shrink animation when grow completes should work. If you want contents to change in the middle that should also go in Completed. If you're not seeing this then there're missing details in your question. Can you please elaborate on the storyboards and the content changes?

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to get this to work. This is what I did (I don't know why I never thought about it):

```
private static void OnDatePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    CalendarEntryHorizontal elem = d as CalendarEntryHorizontal;
    if (elem != null)
    {
        elem.shrinkStoryboard.Completed += (o, ev) =>
        {
            DateTime date = (DateTime)e.NewValue;
            string month = date.ToString("MMMM").Substring(0, 3);
            string day = date.Day.ToString("D2");
            string year = date.Year.ToString("D4");

            // ...

            elem.growStoryboard.Begin();
        };

        elem.shrinkStoryboard.Begin();
    }
}
```